# The first non-zero element in each row

Tags: python, break

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[0,0,0],
      [1,2,0],
      [0,2,1],
      [0,1,2],
      [2,1,3],
      [0,0,0]])
for i in range(6):
  for j in range(3):
    if a[i,j]!=0:
      print(i+1,'-th row,',j+1,'-th column','\nthe 1st non-zero element:',a[i,j],'\n---')
    break
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTrxU.png)

I think the problem caused by `break`, but have no idea how to deal with it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're always breaking on the first iteration of the inner loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the break should be **inside** the if statement

```
if a[i,j]!=0:
      print(i+1,'-th row,',j+1,'-th column','\nthe 1st non-zero element:',a[i,j],'\n---')
      break
```

Answer (score 1):

Indent the `break` once more. It currently only checks the first item of each row for if it is zero or non-zero.

By indenting the `break`, it will only stop searching that row once the condition `a[i,j]!=0` becomes `True`.